# How to write google sheet in python

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to write a google spreadsheet in python.
Even if there is a lot of space on the clipboard, pasting it directly into the google spreadsheet will separate the rows and columns.

clipboard = 
   "1990.6.05 5years 053abd16 
   0610554135 auto 
   housestring~~~~

1915.4.25 5years 053abd16 
 0610554135 auto 
 house string~~~~

1960.9.17 5years 053abd16 
 0610554135 auto 
 housestring~~~~
"

One paragraph goes into the row. By the way, to input in python, you need to replace string with list and specify the range yourself. How can I save it like I typed it directly into googlespreadsheet in python? And is there a way to enter multiple data into one spreadsheet and not overwrite it?

Comment: Take a look at this. It might be helpful. https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/02/an-easy-way-to-read-and-write-to-a-google-spreadsheet-in-python.html.

Comment: Can you provide a sample code of how you're copying into the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is to have the data in a pandas DataFrame, once you get that just use the API from google

[here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python)

Answer (score 0):

There's also a python package called `gspread`, which you can use.
Please find the [documentation](https://gspread.readthedocs.io)